# Equivelant of ciscos "spanning-tree portfast disable" in Juniper parlance

Tags: juniper-ex, ieee-802.1w

On our cisco network switches we have the following configuration:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description Main Internet 1
 xxx
 spanning-tree portfast disable
 spanning-tree bpduguard disable
```

I need to translate that to Junos OS (Juniper network switch).

I believe for bpdugaurd I need this:
`set protocols layer2-control bpdu-block interface ge-0/0/1 disable`

However I can't figure out what the equivalent is of `spanning-tree portfast disable` is.

Can anyone help me understand? I'm running rstp (rapid spanning tree protocol) on the junipers if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juniper's equivalent of `portfast` is `edge` (see the [documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/stp-l2/topics/ref/statement/edge-edit-protocols-stp.html)).

Ports are non-edge by default, which means you don't have to do anything.

If you have something like `set protocols rstp interface all edge` configured and want to selectively run RSTP on an interface as non-edge, you can't.

You either have to explicitly configure each interface the way you want under `protocols rstp` or use `interface-ranges` to aggregate your settings ([documentation](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/interfaces-ethernet-switches/topics/topic-map/switches-interface-range.html#id-configuring-interface-ranges-on-switches)), for example:

```
set interfaces interface-range EDGE member ge-0/0/[1-4]
set protocols rstp interface EDGE edge

set interfaces interface-range NON-EDGE member ge-0/0/*
set protocols rstp interface NON-EDGE
```

Comment: If I have this though: `set protocols rstp interface all edge` how do I over-ride it as non-edge?

Comment: Short answer is, you can't do it that way. I updated my answer to give you some context/ideas.

Comment: So I can't just do `set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/1` (without the edge part) and have it be non-edge?

Comment: @Brad - there isn't really a non-edge configuration in Junos.  In the "edge" documentation referenced above, it even mentions that under RSTP "this statement has no effect on the switch operation if you configure it".  If the port is configured to run RSTP (set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/1) and the port is up and doesn't receive a BPDU, it is in Edge mode.  If it is up and receives a BPDU, then it will transition to non-edge.  This is the case regardless of whether you configure (set protocols rstp interface ge-0/0/1 edge) or not.